Java LinkageError after upgrading Vespa from version 7.113.28 to 8.357.16
I have a Java component designed to write documents using Vespa. It was working fine with Vespa version 7.113.28, but after upgrading to version 8.357.16, I encounter a LinkageError. Below is the relevant part of my code:
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp);
ZoneId timeZone = ZoneId.of("UTC+8");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, timeZone);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter);

DocumentAccess access = DocumentAccess.createForNonContainer();
AsyncSession session = access.createAsyncSession(new AsyncParameters());
DocumentType type = access.getDocumentTypeManager().getDocumentType("QATracker");
DocumentId id = new DocumentId("id:my-search:QATracker::" + custAcctID + "_" + timestamp);
Document docIn = new Document(type, id);
DocumentPut put = new DocumentPut(docIn);
Document document = put.getDocument();
document.setFieldValue("responseDate", formattedDate);
document.setFieldValue("responseDateTime", timestamp);
document.setFieldValue("content", content);
document.setFieldValue("custAcctID", custAcctID);

session.put(docIn);

Error message:
[2024-07-01 14:04:13.698] ERROR   container        Container.com.yahoo.jrt.Transport    
    fatal error in com.yahoo.jrt.TransportThread@6982fc54
    exception=
    java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'void com.yahoo.component.Version.<init>(com.yahoo.text.Utf8Array)' the class loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader @37baddde of the current class, com/yahoo/messagebus/network/rpc/RPCTarget, and the class loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader @23bff419 for the method's defining class, com/yahoo/component/Version, have different Class objects for the type com/yahoo/text/Utf8Array used in the signature (com.yahoo.messagebus.network.rpc.RPCTarget is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader @37baddde, parent loader 'bootstrap'; com.yahoo.component.Version is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader @23bff419, parent loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.yahoo.messagebus.network.rpc.RPCTarget.handleRequestDone(RPCTarget.java:141)
    at com.yahoo.jrt.InvocationClient.handleReply(InvocationClient.java:61)
    at com.yahoo.jrt.Connection.handlePackets(Connection.java:280)
    at com.yahoo.jrt.Connection.read(Connection.java:295)
    at com.yahoo.jrt.Connection.handleReadEvent(Connection.java:311)
    at com.yahoo.jrt.TransportThread.handleIOEvents(TransportThread.java:150)
    at com.yahoo.jrt.TransportThread.run(TransportThread.java:329)
    at com.yahoo.jrt.TransportThread$Run.run(TransportThread.java:24)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

pom.xml Configuration:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yahoo.vespa</groupId>
    <artifactId>documentapi</artifactId>
    <version>8.357.16</version> <!-- Find latest version at search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.yahoo.vespa%20a:documentapi -->
</dependency>


What could be causing this LinkageError after upgrading Vespa?
How can I resolve this issue to ensure compatibility with the new Vespa version?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

During debugging, I observed that the LinkageError occurs at the line handleRequestDone within RPCTarget.class where a new Version object is instantiated with a version string corresponding to 3.10.

As this is an upgrade across a major version, please review https://docs.vespa.ai/en/vespa8-release-notes.html - please let me know if something is missing from this

The pom.xml snippet you provided is used for building standalone java clients for feeding documents, as described here.
However, your error message indicates that you are deploying your jar file as a component, probably adding a DocumentProcessor via services.xml? If so, I recommend to take a look at one of our sample apps, e.g. document processing
Please, also make sure to update any references to old Vespa 7 versions in your pom.xml.
